# React-Native iOS accurate active input position

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I have tried to use some the existing solution for iOS keyboard avoiding but none of the existing solutions seems to be working properly with some of my rather complicated views and I am now having to implement my own system. Thus far I have managed to come up with the following which works quite good:

```
    _keyboardDidShow(e) {
        const keyboardHeight = e.endCoordinates.height;
        const windowHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;
        const keyboardTop = windowHeight - keyboardHeight;
        const margin = 10;

        const currentlyFocusedField = TextInput.State.currentlyFocusedField();
        UIManager.measureInWindow(currentlyFocusedField, (x, y, width, height) => {
            const fieldBottom = y + height;
            const offset = fieldBottom - keyboardTop + 10;

            if (offset > 0) {
                this.setState({ offsetY: -1 * offset, offsettingKeyboard: true });
            }
        });
    }
```

I should mention that these inputs are inside ScrollViews which are themselves in a bunch of other stuff.

The problem is that when the handler is called for a TextInput that has not been scrolled up inside its view, the proper "fieldBottom" position is obtained without adding the height while the height addition is needed for the real position of a field inside a view that has been scrolled.

I cannot decide if this is a bug or if I am missing something. Is there perhaps a way I can check if the input's parent has been scrolled?

Comment: Way cool I didn't know about `measureInWindow` is this documented somewhere, I would love to learn more about it.

Comment: @Noitidart I don't think it's documented, I found in the TypeScript definitions

Comment: Oh interesting may you please link me to it, and also please give a short description about it.